# How to check if a control is fitting on the screen area or is out of the range?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I really appreciate if somebody with patience could correct my code, (coding is not my job).

Pushing the `button1`, I would check if a Control as a `TextView` is currently outside the screen as a consequence that there are to many controls according with device screen size, but I don't know how to do it.
(I've still checked other similar post but I've not understood, so sorry but this is why I'm here)

This is a my `Activity.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <GridLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="5"
        android:rowCount="6"
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout1">
        <RadioButton
            android:text="Total:"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonFT"
            android:checked="true" 
            android:tooltipText="Fissa % di H2O" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:id="@+id/editTextTotFlour"
            android:maxWidth="150px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="10"
            android:gravity="right" />
        <TextView
            android:text="kg"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:maxWidth="30px"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:id="@+id/editTextTotFlourPer100"
            android:maxWidth="150px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="100"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:gravity="right" />
        <TextView
            android:text="%"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:maxWidth="30px"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        <RadioButton
            android:text="H2O:"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonH2O" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:id="@+id/editTextH2O"
            android:maxWidth="150px"
            android:text="6"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right" />
        <TextView
            android:text="l"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:maxWidth="30px"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:id="@+id/editTextH2OPer100"
            android:maxWidth="150px"
            android:text="60"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right" />
        <TextView
            android:text="%"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:maxWidth="30px"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:text=" Something:"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        <EditText
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/editTextSaltPer100"
            android:maxWidth="150px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="35"
            android:gravity="right" />
        <TextView
            android:text="g"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:maxWidth="30px"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        <EditText
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/editTextSalt"
            android:maxWidth="150px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="21"
            android:gravity="right" />
        <TextView
            android:text="g"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:maxWidth="30px"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    </GridLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20px"
        android:layout_weight="0" 
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
        <View
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/viewDivider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="#808080" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridLayout  
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"    
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="6"
        android:rowCount="4"
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout2">
        <TextView
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="6"
            android:text="Temperature"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewTH20"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text=" Ti:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/textViewTI"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:textAlignment="textEnd" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:id="@+id/editTextTI"
            android:maxWidth="150px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="21"
            android:gravity="right" />
        <TextView
            android:text="°"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/textView21"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="Ta:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/textViewTA"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:id="@+id/editTextTA"
            android:maxWidth="150px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="25"
            android:gravity="right" />
        <TextView
            android:text="°"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/textView23"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="Tf:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/textViewTF"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:id="@+id/editTextTF"
            android:maxWidth="150px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="24"
            android:gravity="right" />
        <TextView
            android:text="°"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/textView25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Tm:"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/textViewTM"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:textAlignment="textEnd" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:id="@+id/editTextTM"
            android:maxWidth="150px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="5"
            android:gravity="right" />
        <TextView
            android:text="°"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/textView26"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    </GridLayout>

    <RelativeLayout             
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2">
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:prompt="@string/dawn_media_prompt"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />

    <GridLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout3">
        <TextView
            android:text="Hello 1\nHello 2\nHello 3\nHello 4\nHello 5\n"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewInfo"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:clickable="true" />
    </GridLayout>
    
</LinearLayout>
```

that produces the interface shown on the attached picture:

[image]

As you can see on the XML, `textViewInfo` has some 5 lines of text, and the control doesn't fit the screen. This is what I want to get.

In `MainActivity.cs` I've tried to get one control and to sum the height but something is wrong.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using System;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Graphics;

namespace abc_xamarin
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        RadioButton radioButtonFT, radioButtonH2O;
        Spinner spinner;
        TextView textViewInfo;
        GridLayout gridLayout1, gridLayout2, gridLayout3;
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout1, relativeLayout2;
        Button button1;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            radioButtonFT = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radioButtonFT);
            radioButtonH2O = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radioButtonH2O);

            relativeLayout1 = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.relativeLayout1);
            relativeLayout2 = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.relativeLayout2);
            gridLayout1 = FindViewById<GridLayout>(Resource.Id.gridLayout1);
            gridLayout2 = FindViewById<GridLayout>(Resource.Id.gridLayout2);
            gridLayout3 = FindViewById<GridLayout>(Resource.Id.gridLayout3);

            spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner);
            spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(spinner_ItemSelected);
            var adapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(this, Resource.Array.dawn_media_array, Resource.Layout.custom_spinner_text);
            adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Resource.Layout.custom_spinner_text);
            spinner.Adapter = adapter;

            radioButtonFT.CheckedChange += (o, e) =>
            rdBtnFT();

            radioButtonH2O.CheckedChange += (o, e) =>
            rdBtnH2O();

            textViewInfo = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.editTextTotFlour);

            button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            
            button1.Click += (o, e) =>
            btnBtn();
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

        private void rdBtnFT()
        {
            if (radioButtonFT.Checked == true)
            {
                radioButtonH2O.Checked = false;
                //do something
            }
        }

        private void rdBtnH2O()
        {
            if (radioButtonH2O.Checked == true)
            {
                radioButtonFT.Checked = false;
                //do something
            }
        }

        private void spinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
        }

        private void btnBtn()
        {
            //checkScreenContext();
            //gridLayout1, relativeLayout1, gridLayout2, relativeLayout2, button1, textViewInfo
            int sumY = 0;

            var location = new int[2];

            gridLayout1.GetLocationOnScreen(location);
            sumY = sumY + location[1];
            var sizeY = gridLayout1.Height;
            sumY = sumY + sizeY;

            //relativeLayout1.GetLocationOnScreen(location);
            sizeY = relativeLayout1.Height;
            sumY = sumY + sizeY;

            //gridLayout2.GetLocationOnScreen(location);
            sizeY = gridLayout2.Height;
            sumY = sumY + sizeY;

            //relativeLayout2.GetLocationOnScreen(location);
            sizeY = relativeLayout2.Height;
            sumY = sumY + sizeY;

            //button1.GetLocationOnScreen(location);           
            sizeY = button1.Height;
            sumY = sumY + sizeY;

            //textViewInfo.GetLocationOnScreen(location);
            sizeY = textViewInfo.Height;
            sumY = sumY + sizeY;

            string text = "Y: " + sumY.ToString();

            Toast.MakeText(this, text, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }


    }
}
```

I also tried other way to get the position of `textViewInfo` but I've got a position as (0,0).

I really appreciate if somebody could correct my code.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fit everything on the screen, you can either: use a ScrollLayout that'll let you scroll down an up in case there's too much content to fit your screen; or use a ListLayout, that'll let you scroll only the list of items you're displaying.

Watching the  image, I guess a combination of the two would be needed.

Comment: I'll try, thank Krisam! This is my first Xamarin-Android app : )

Answer (score 1):

Calling `getWidth`, `getHeight`, `getX`, `getY`, etc. before the UI component is displayed on the interface usually returns `0`.

You could call `View.post(Runnable)`. By looking up the definition of this method, we can see that the Runnable operation is executed between `attachedToWindow()` to `detachedFromWindow()` of the View, and the position of the View has been calculated at this time.

For example you want get the position of `textViewInfo`:

```
textViewInfo.Post(() =>
        {
            var location = new int[2];
            textViewInfo.GetLocationOnScreen(location);
            // you could get the position here
        });
```

Comment: It seems that doesn't work as I expect, in this way, I get that the `location = 279, 240` for `textViewInfo`, but if I get position for `gridLayout3.Post` the location gives `0, 1213`. So I tried  to get `textViewInfo.Height` but IF the `TextView` height has One line or More, I get always the same value.

Comment: As well, if I include `textViewInfo.GetY()` in `textViewInfo.Post()` method I still get `0`.

Comment: @orecchionebruno First,i found your `textViewInfo` refer to the wrong id (`textViewInfo = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.editTextTotFlour);`),Second,`textViewInfo.GetY()`  will get its y-coordinate in its parent container,so it will get  `0` (you could set a mariginTop to verify that).